# Changing images based on stylesheet

Tags: php, html, css, image

Is it possible to switch out images based on what stylesheet is being used on the page?

For example, I have a normal and a nightview stylesheet which users can switch between. Although I'm guessing the solution might be with CSS, here's my pseudocode attempt in PHP:

```
        $css = "/.css"
        if (css=normal.css){    
            echo "<img src='1.1.1.jpg'>";
        }
        if (css=nightview.css){ 
            echo "<img src='1.1.1i.jpg'>";
        }
```

Any tips on how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Store first the users selected theme (normal,nightview) inside a SESSION or a Cookie then echo it out on your link header.

```
<link href="<?php echo $myCss;?>" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Now inside the css you can target the image using a id or class and change that image or any element accordingly.

```
#MyImage {

 background-image: url("black.png");

}
```

Comment: That works great for a single background image. But what about other images?

Comment: if images is inside a theme.css then you can target is per class name example `.image1{background-image: url("black-0.png"); }` or `.image2{background-image: url("black-1.png"); }`